# How to debug: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'customer'

Tags: magento2, theme, layout-update

Getting a critical error that doesn't seem to be affecting anything on the frontend that I can notice.

> main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'customer'.

Error is caught in `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool::moveElementInStructure` when it's trying to do

```
$structure->setAsChild($element, $destination, $alias);
```

The arguments have values...

```
$element = top.links
$destination = customer
$alias = top.links
```

I've narrowed it down to the file `app/design/frontend/MyConpany/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` causing this problem. When this file is removed, no errors are logged, but there are no `top.links` or `customer` references there. How do you debug this?

`app/design/frontend/MyConpany/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`:

```
 <container name="above.header.msg" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="above-header--msg">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top-header-content" template="Magento_Theme::html/top-content.phtml" />
     </container>
     <referenceContainer name="header.panel" htmlClass="panel header page-content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
           <arguments>
              <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
           </arguments>
        </block>
     </referenceContainer>
     <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
           <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">60</argument>
        </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>
     <referenceContainer name="main">
        <container name="content.top" label="Main Content Top" />
        <container name="content" label="Main Content Area" />
        <container name="content.aside" label="Main Content Aside" />
        <container name="content.bottom" label="Main Content Bottom" />
     </referenceContainer>
     <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
        <container name="page.bottom" label="Before Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="content" />
     </referenceContainer>
     <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer">
           <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer</argument>
           </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml" />
     </referenceContainer>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey" />
     </referenceContainer>
     <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end" />
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that there is another layout file somewhere which is supposed to reference the `above.header.msg` container that's defined here and add a block element named `customer`, but isn't doing so for some reason.

This file is overriding `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` , and the `above.header.msg` is the only container declaration in the default.xml override file you've provided, that isn't in  `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` . Also, there is a block named `top.links` in this base default.xml file.

I'd first start by removing the `<move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end" />` declaration, since the error is related to the moveElementInStructure. If that works, I'd investigate the existence of the `copyright` element being referred to.

Otherwise, I'd look through the custom code for a `customer` block to see if there's one in a layout file, if so, try and figure out why it's not behaving correctly. Next, I'd look through custom blocks to see if there's any block creation logic that's not behaving. Finally, I'd see if there was a layout which was in fact removing a `customer` block, thereby causing this issue.

That's what comes to mind right now. It's hard to say more without more context.

I would be interested in your findings.

Good luck

Doc reference to the default.xml file:
[basic layouts](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html#basic-layouts)

**UPDATE**
There's a reference to these types of critical messages being logged while in developer mode here: [Issue:#3507](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3507#issuecomment-221278166). There's also a recently opened issue here: [Issue:#7715](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7715).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Magento 2.3.3 CE, and the Solwin Freego child theme. The problem I was experiencing was caused by the child theme not creating the block for the customer "Sign in" / Account menu. When the front page loads, the error message is reported in the log, "main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'customer'". I happened to notice that the customer "Sign in" link was missing from the top of the page. Only "Create An Account" link was showing. I don't know whether this was caused by changes I had made to the child theme.

My problem was resolved by using the Freego parent theme instead of the child theme. Now no error is reported, and the "Sign in" link is once again visible at the top of the page.